# Get first 10 lines and last 10 lines in textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I need to get the first  10 lines and last 10 lines on a multiline text in a textbox in a Windows Forms application.

```
ex.(textbox values)
Chicken
Chinese
Beef
Pork
Mutton
Fish
Prawn
Vegetarian
--
---
```

Comment: Show us what you got...

Comment: @Stefan i want to get first 10 line and and last 10 line string values.I try with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Linq*:

```
  var source = myTextBox.Lines;

  var first = source.Take(10);
  var last = source.Skip(source.Length - 10);
```

Now, let's print out the first values into, say, `myReportTextBox`:

```
 myReportTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, first);
```

Comment: plus one, I never knew there is a property called as lines for TextBox in C#.

Comment: @Dimtry this way can get first 10 and last element in text box. But how this can apply for a windows.form.TextBox? i wand to get element in  a textbox and print. In this way i get System.Linq.Enumerable values. How i convert in to string?

Comment: @Sandun Tharaka: if you want combine the `IEnumerable<T>` back into string you can use `String.Join` (see my edit)

Comment: @Dimitry i have another problem, what is the method to getting within 20 to last (elements within 20 to last).

Comment: @Sandun Tharaka: operate with `Skip()` and `Take()`: if you want to skip `20` items and then take all the rest: `var from20ToLast = source.Skip(20);`

Comment: @Dimitry Thanks for detail answers. It help me lot.

Answer (score 7):

```
var r1 = textBoxValues.Select(t=>t.values).Take(10);

var r2 = textBoxValues.Select(t=>t.values).Reverse().Take(10);
```

Comment: I think OP needs to get the lines, i.e. `textBoxValues` first. Maybe a `Split`?

Comment: Elegant and easy to read through LINQ, but how would you apply this to a Windows.Forms.TextBox? Probably using something like `TextBox.Lines.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: You both are right, I assume values are stored in texBoxValues

Comment: this way can get first 10 and last element in text box. But @ dlatikay mentioned problem occur. how this can apply for a windows.form.TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` inherits from `TextBoxBase`, which has a property:

```
public string[] Lines { get; set; }
```

You can query this property for its length, and when it has more than 10 elements (it is a plain array-of-string), then you can take the first ten and last ten from there. If it is a requirement that the first ten and last ten do not overlap, then you will need to ensure that the array count is at least 20.